# mysql insert(working with expiration date)

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering how insert now() + 3 days into a mysql insert.

kinda like this `mysql_query(INSERT INTO what_ever ('','',now(), now() + 3 days)` Ignore if this code doesn't work it just and example.

I was wondering how I can do this. I want to add an expiration time so when users log in and its on that date or past it will automatically remove the item. I don't need help removing I just need help adding it the date to the now function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not `now() + 3 days`. Use:

```
now() + INTERVAL 3 DAY
```

Comment: yper yours worked perfectly the DATE_ADD doesn't work for my system apparently. Thank you.

Comment: @user979626: This is strange, `DATE_ADD()` should work fine, too. Which MySQL version you have and what syntax error you got?

Comment: I don't get a syntax error it just doesn't add to mysql database. The row doesn't add. For what mysql version I have 5.5.8.

Comment: Kinda doubt it when I do it all by itself with no other coding involved. There is no strange coding just the mysql_query code.

Comment: @user979626: If there is no syntax error but the row is not added, you are probably getting a run-time error. Have you tried the same query from phpMyAdmin? Or catching the run-time error?

Answer (score 3):

Use [MySQL's DATEADD function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add):

```
INSERT INTO what_ever ('', '', now(), DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY));
```